# What control to render dynamic HTML text on an aspx page

Tags: asp.net

Page_Load generates a string of HTML for a dashboard. (html)

What control on an aspx page to bind that "text" to so when the page renders you see the tables, and buttons within?

Tried

With dhtml.Text = html but I don't see the buttons.  I do see the tables as well as the borders of cells that I expect.

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject any text/html into your ASPX page using: <% =GetMyText() %> where "GetMyText()" is a public or protected method in your code behind that returns a string.

You can also drop a Literal control onto a form and set the text via its "Text" property.

But if you want to do things the ASP.NET way, you might use a Gridview or Repeater to display tabular/repeating data, and Databind to it with some data.

If you are starting out with ASP.NET, you would probably be better off learning [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) as it is easier to get your head around if you are used to writing HTML. ASP.NET Web Forms, which you are using, generally tries to insulate you from HTML, CSS, and Javascript by giving you controls that you drop onto the page and bind data to. The controls do a lot of work for you, but take away almost all control of your HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Comment: Found this Fri afternoon as well.  This is what I was looking for though!

Answer (score 0):

I use javascript to dynamically create html elements. Your page_load function could register a javascript function which creates the elements you need.

Comment: The codebehind is pulling data from backend and using that as the basis for this grouping of tables and elements for presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you were downvoted, but a very simple one to use is the [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Basically, just add a span or div to your .aspx file and give it an ID and the runat="server" attribute.

Then, in your code behind just set the InnerHtml property of that control to your generated html.